# How to combine a property type, to match another properties type

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following use case with a JSON schema. I have a metadata object of a setting. In our case a setting can be of type string/real/integer/boolean.

In this object I have 4 fields: default/minimum/maximum each define a property of the setting.
Now what I want to achieve is that when the type of de default value is an integer, also the minimum/maximum values are integers.

The schema I have come up with so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "setting-value": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "number"
        },
        {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      ]
    },
    "setting-meta": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "type",
        "default"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Real",
            "Integer",
            "Boolean",
            "String"
          ]
        },
        "minimum": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/setting-value"
        },
        "maximum": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/setting-value"
        },
        "default": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/setting-value"
        },
        "value": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/setting-value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is possible for the #/definitions/setting-meta to have support for the different types. However it does not define that if for example the value of TYPE is equal to Real/Integer that the types of minimum/maximum/default/value should all be of type number.

I would use these definitions as follows

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$ref": "schema-definition-above.json#/definitions/setting-meta"
}
```

According the the current schema, all examples below are VALID, however they should be valid/invalid as suggested:

Valid JSon object:

```
{
    "name": "Enabled",
    "type": "Boolean",
    "minimum": false,
    "maximum": true,
    "default": true,
    "value": true
}
```

Invalid json object, minimum/maximum/default don't have the same type:

```
{
    "name": "Enabled",
    "type": "Boolean",
    "minimum": false,
    "maximum": 1,
    "default": "value",
    "value": true
}
```

Invalid json object: type, does not match the actual type of the values

```
{
    "name": "Enabled",
    "unit": "enabled/disabled",
    "configId": "Accumulator",
    "displayName": "Enable or disable this machine",
    "type": "Integer",
    "minimum": false,
    "maximum": true,
    "default": true,
    "value": true
}
```

My question:
Is it possible to put these kinds of dependencies into a JSON schema? The only kind of dependency I have foudn so far is with property dependencies indicating that if one property is set, another should also be set.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Extended that use case with some JSON objects that should be validated or invalidated with the referenced schema.

Comment: Currently your schema only has definitions. Could you modify it to have some validation constraints please? Then I can help. I can help faster if you also provide a few examples of what you would like to be valid and invalid

Comment: Hello Relequestual,
Thank you for your reply. I added some examples as you suggested, hopefully this makes the issue more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do conditional validation where you have a known set of possible conditions, you should use the `if/then/else` keywords, in combination with with `allOf`.

In this schema, the first schema in `allOf` defines your general structure and overall requirements. The second schema applies the `then` constraint if the `if` schema validates successfully.

You would need to replicate the second schema for each condition that you have.

You can see this schema working at [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVIQA2ugPISSiANpbkiOEkvaQ1fi2q5+FAJa4wJ67duoKAJ7O3ha+lqi48ACu+CbmNmF+IABKuHoaoYl2AJLwFLiCLhkJWWQAQiwsumnwxaXhIADKFPxu8IKomWEAul2WAL59-Zoldvy4AI5RbuMicX12gcEgI1moIrgShFG6FHWJqPCE+Lido4i9JcOZPr6obsZQVgtkDk4u7p4h50lLp0+3eqoTBsMB7J6oZqtdpneqDH6IeFha7nfx4WoAl6oaiEKgueAABUczlcHi8mIRdgAegAKfBtNz4GIAHyIAA9GSyNlsdhRmQA3PRRXAASjQ33qiyC-1I8UlDTB0I6IBetkucJeSN8WuQWsu-RWIDcUBgFkOxxlZEIiEVbUEiDY-1WZD+JkhLTt+3Wm22uzdIGttphKzNIHp8E5sSeW10YFO8AN-SAA) (link is preloaded with the below schema and sample data)

(The use of `patternProperties` is just a space saver. You could define each property individually.)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "allOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "Real",
            "Integer",
            "Boolean",
            "String"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "default",
        "name"
      ]
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "const": "String"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "patternProperties": {
          "^(minimum|maximum|default|value)$": {
            "type": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply, this helps me a lot.

Do you have any pointers to some more advanced guides on the internet where such topics are addressed? I find it hard locate those using google searches.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, there isn't much up to date guides like this. We haven't had the spare time to update the learning resources. You're best bet for regular help is post here on SO or join the official slack (where we monitor SO anyway). Link is on the website as "discussion".

Comment: I have one follow question, is there an: if ... then ... elsif ... then .. kind of structure, or do have have to apply a nested if within the "then" statement?

Comment: There's no else if. You COULD nest inside `then`, but it's preferable to create an extra schema inside the `allOf` and modify to your requirements.

Comment: So my allOf, will simply have an array of objects with an "if type == >type, then ...".
Clear. Thanks.